# Sphere image conversion from flat image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three js to convert the flat image to spherical image type.I read the document from [three js](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene). And tried the below source code.

// spherical_conversion.html

```
<html>    
<head>
    <title>Conversion flat image to spherical image</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sample_image.jpg')
            })
        );
        sphere.scale.x = -1;
        scene.add(sphere);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I am tried here is the sample_image.jpg is a flat image.Using the three js library converting spherical image.

I ran the piece of code didn't get any error in console. And not even get the expected result as well . I got the blank page after ran this code.

What i am expected here is convert the flat image into spherical image.Please let me know to get this up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: missing `new` in front of `THREE.ImageUtils`

Comment: Thanks for your information @gaitat .I found that I missed some mandatory fields like renderAnimationFrame so didn't get the image in canvas.Get more sample [here](https://github.com/turban/photosphere) :) .This will fixed the issues.